# A general query while training

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Do the following conditions are meant to be the same. As per my knowledge, I think they are the same. Please guide me.

```
def Model_a():
  return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='Model1')
def Model_b():
  return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='Model2')
def Model_1(Model_a, Model_b):
  return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1,output2])
def Model_2(Model_a, Model_b):
  return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

#Condition 1
Model_1.train_on_batch(x,[y,z])


#Condition 2
Model_2.train_on_batch(x,z)
Model_b.train_on_batch(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let there are two outputs for one input. Model_a has output output_a and Model_b has output output_b.

```
def Model_a(): 
      output_a =   ...  (layers of model_a)
      return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_a, name='Model1')

  def Model_b():
      output_b =   ...   (layers of model_b)
      return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_b, name='Model2')
```

Now, if you want to define a model that has both outputs merged in one model as:

```
def Model_1(...):
  output_a =  ...     (layers of model_a)
  output_b =  ...     (layers of model_b) 
  return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output_a,output_b])
```

Then condition 1:

```
Model_1.train_on_batch(x,[y,z])
```

And Condition 2:

```
Model_a.train_on_batch(x,z)
Model_b.train_on_batch(x,y)
```

In this case, condition-1 and condition-2 are equivalent. Graphically, both conditions can be demonstrated by the following diagram.

[image].

Hope this will answer your ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. Can I also use this statement to train the Model_1 also? 

`Model_1.train_on_batch(x,z)`

Comment: You can train Model_1 with both target outputs.

Comment: I have to ask that do these statements are equal now
`Model_a.train_on_batch(input,output)`
`Model_1.train_on_batch(input,[output1, output2])`

#Statement 2
`Model_a.train_on_batch(input,output)`
`Model_1.train_on_batch(input,output)`
`Model_b
.train_on_batch(input,output)`

Comment: 1. Model_1.train_on_batch(input,output) has one output here which will give error. 
2. Statement 1: >> Model_1.train_on_batch(input,[output1, output2])
    Statement 2: Model_a.train_on_batch(input,output); 
                         Model_b .train_on_batch(input,output)
Now, Statement-1 and statement-2 are equal. But as you have provided, if you train Model_a first and then Model_1, in that case, if you do use trained weights of Model_a then it would be different than statement-2.

Comment: Let's make it a bit simple. Please confirm me that do these separate training methods [Method 1](https://github.com/RaphaelMeudec/deblur-gan/blob/master/scripts/train.py) and [Method 2](https://github.com/leftthomas/ImageDeblurring/blob/master/main.py) are same ?

Comment: Since both branches of the network are separate so whether you train each network independent or both together, they will eventually converge to the same point.